# foundation 6 tabs not switching tabs on click

Tags: zurb-foundation

I am making a website using foundation 6 and I am trying to add the tabs component to my website, the tabs are styled the same as the once on the foundation docs but when I go to click on them it does not switch between

tabs

```
<ul class="tabs" data-tabs id="example-tabs">
  <li class="tabs-title is-active"><a href="#panel1" aria-selected="true">Tab 1</a></li>
  <li class="tabs-title"><a href="#panel2">Tab 2</a></li>
  <li class="tabs-title"><a href="#panel3">Tab 3</a></li>
  <li class="tabs-title"><a href="#panel4">Tab 4</a></li>
  <li class="tabs-title"><a href="#panel5">Tab 5</a></li>
  <li class="tabs-title"><a href="#panel6">Tab 6</a></li>
</ul>
tabs 
<div class="tabs-content" data-tabs-content="example-tabs">
  <div class="tabs-panel is-active" id="panel1">
    <p>one</p>
    <p>Check me out! I&#39;m a super cool Tab panel with text content!</p>
  </div>
  <div class="tabs-panel" id="panel2">
    <p>two</p>
    <img class="thumbnail" src="assets/img/rectangle-7.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="tabs-panel" id="panel3">
    <p>three</p>
    <p>Check me out! I&#39;m a super cool Tab panel with text content!</p>
  </div>
  <div class="tabs-panel" id="panel4">
    <p>four</p>
    <img class="thumbnail" src="assets/img/rectangle-2.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="tabs-panel" id="panel5">
    <p>five</p>
    <p>Check me out! I&#39;m a super cool Tab panel with text content!</p>
  </div>
  <div class="tabs-panel" id="panel6">
    <p>six</p>
    <img class="thumbnail" src="assets/img/rectangle-8.jpg">
  </div>
</div>

<script src="js/vendor/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/vendor/what-input.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/foundation.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to initialize the Foundation javascript, making the following call:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $(document).foundation();
        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is having this problem (like I was) and you're just building in the default app.component I added "$(document).foundation();" to the public ngOnInit() like this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app works!';

    public ngOnInit() {
        $(document).foundation();
    }

}
```

I know this is probably a "hacky" answer but if you're just playing around and trying to get something to work it worked for me. Good luck.